# Joomla 2.5 Login Form page shows a blank page

Tags: joomla, authentication, joomla2.5

On the front end of my Joomla 2.5.8 installation, ".../index.php/component/users/?view=login" shows up as a blank page.

Basically, I am trying to make a link on my navigation bar that links to a booking system. Only registered users can access this booking system. If they are logged in successfully, the booking page will show up, else, a login screen will appear and request the user to log in to access the booking system.

My Joomla menu structure is like this:

1) Booking system menu item is a menu item alias and has public access. Any person can see this link on my menu navigation bar.

2) The menu item alias is linked to another menu item residing on a different menu and has registered access. This different menu is not published anywhere.

I followed the guide from this page: [Show a joomla article to registered users only, or a login screen if not logged in yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495498/show-a-joomla-article-to-registered-users-only-or-a-login-screen-if-not-logged)

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your template. It have errors or undefined functions. Try to put at the end of your url &template=system  (.../index.php/component/users/?view=login&template=system). I will try to come back with more details and option to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have appended &template=system at the back and the login module shows up. I will check through my template and enable maximum error reporting and see how that goes..